# Jackson array or string: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I know similar questions have been asked before, but they did not resolve my particular scenario.

I am using jackson to bind json to pojo object.  The problem is that the Json result will sometimes be a single value:

```
attributes: [
    {
        name: "IDs",
        value: [
            76715
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Updated",
        value: false
    },
    {
        name: "Merged",
        value: false
    },
    {
        name: "Source",
        value: "db"
    }
]
```

My question is, how do I account for this in my attribute object?

I tried string, then tried an array then tried to combine them.

```
private List value = new ArrayList();

public List getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(List value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value.add(value);
}
```

So far nothing has worked for all the possibilities for "value".

Answer (score 1):

An `Attribute` class which define `value` as `Object` will do the job:

```
public static class Attribute {
  private String name;
  private Object value;

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public Object getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public void setValue(Object value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Also, when you get the value, you can use instanceof to determine what you have.